# Por que no me funciona la estructura for?

Tags: c

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de un cajero automatico en el lenguaje de C , quiero que cuando el usuario intente mas de 3 veces colocar el Nip , le diga que la tarjeta esta bloqueada , pero veo que el ciclo for no me funciona y no entiendo porque, apenas estoy iniciando con este lenguaje.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    int cantidad;`
    int saldo=10000;
    int Tarjeta;
    int Nip;
    int indice;
    char Menu;
    
    printf("Digite su numero de tarjeta de credito\n");
    scanf("%i",&Tarjeta);
     printf("Digite su clave de acceso\n");
     scanf("%i",&Nip);

    if(Nip==333){
        printf("Bienvenido\n Elija la opcion\n");
        printf("1.Retiro\n 2.Saldo\n");
        scanf("%i",&Menu);
    switch(Menu){
        case 1: printf("Cual es la cantidad que desea retirar\n");
        scanf("%i",&cantidad);
        if(cantidad>saldo){
            printf("fondos insuficientes\n");
        }else{
            printf("Monto dispensado: %i",&cantidad);
            saldo= (saldo-cantidad);
            printf("El saldo disponible es: %i",&saldo);
        }
        break;
        case 2: printf("Su balance es: %i",&saldo);
        break;
        default: printf("opcion no valida");    
    }
}else {

    for(indice=1; indice<=3; indice++){
        printf("Digite su clave de acceso\n");
        scanf("%i",Nip);    
    }
    if(indice>3){
        printf("Tarjeta Bloqueada");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Creo que el planteamiento, no es correcto. En cuanto te equivocas la primera vez en poner el Nip, pasas al for. Te pide 3 veces la clave, sin importar que sea correcta para acto seguido salirse. Al if siguiente no entra debido a que en el for al llegar indice=3 se sale y en el if nunca te va a entrar poque pides que el indice sea mayor que 3. ¿Te salta algun error en el compilador? Detrás de:  int cantidad;` hay una tilde que no debería estar.
  (yo en este caso usaria un do while al pedir los datos para dar acceso)

Comment: En el scanf que tienes dentro del for le falta &, y te va a dar problemas. Por otra parte, como dice @YORS el planteamiento no es correcto.

Comment: ¿Qué significa "*el ciclo for no me funciona*"? ¿Qué está pasando y qué esperabas que pasase?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster esperaba que pidiera 3 veces el nip si el usuario introducia de manera incorrecta y que si lo hacia 3 veces le mostrara lo que esta dentro del if que dice que la tarjeta ha sido bloqueada

Comment: lo que @YORS dice es lo correcto, si esperas que luego de digitar, por 3 veces (que es lo que se hace en el ciclo for), cuando evalúas que el índice sea mayor que 3 no se cumple la condición.